# Converting Objective C to C# - What is the equivalent to this code?

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I am converting some Objective C code to C# for use in a Monotouch iPhone app.

In Objective C, the following equivalence condition is tested:

```
if ([cell.backgroundView class] != [UIView class])
    ... do something
```

cell is a `UITableViewCell`.

In C#, I'd like to test the same condition using (so far) the following:

```
if ( !(cell.BackgroundView is UIView))
    ... do something
```

Is the understanding of the Objective C code correct, i.e. it tests the type of `cell`? What would the equivalent be in C#?

Comment: Cool!  I didn't know you could develop for the iPhone in C#.

Comment: Check out Monotouch - it's great!

Comment: @Cheeso, see [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks right, unless `UITableViewCell` inherits from `UIView`.

in which case you'll need

```
if (cell.BackgroundView.GetType() !=  typeof(UIView))
    ... do something
```

Comment: Well, it's not whether UITableViewCell inherits from UIView, but whether the background view inherits from UIView, which it must to be assigned to cell.BackgroundView.  So you'll need to use the code provided here.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to test for type in Objective-C is like this:

```
if ([[cell backgroundView] isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
  //the backgroundView is a UIView (or some subclass thereof)
}
```

If you want to test for explicit membership, you can do:

```
if ([[cell backgroundView] isMemberOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
  //the backgroundView is a UIView (and not a subclass thereof)
}
```

Comment: Great, I have seen other examples which also recommends this way of checking. The question then is, what `if ([cell.backgroundView class] != [UIView class])` check for?

Comment: @Ryan Bates: that's basically "isNotMemberOfClass" (if such a method existed); it's also equivalent to `![view isMemberOfClass:[UIView class]]`